# Block Stack Overflow scrapers from Google or DuckDuckGo search results

Tags: google-search, search-engine, duckduckgo

As you may know, there are a number of websites (such as `wenda.io`) that scrape content from StackOverflow (and other StackExchange sites). I couldn’t care less that they do this, and indeed they are at perfect liberty to do so as long as they attribute where they got it from (I’ve also done my fair share of reporting those sites that don’t do this), except these sites are polluting my search results.

The problem is that there are dozens of these sites, with new ones seeming to appear every day. They often appear right beside the corresponding Stack Overflow page, but sometimes they don’t. The sites themselves are usually terribly formatted and difficult to use, and of course don't have all the “related” boxes that I find super useful on Stack Overflow (though they have their own poor imitations). Furthermore, I don’t want to support these sites by using them.

Is there a simple way to exclude these scraper sites from Google search results? (I'd be happy if you could find a solution for DuckDuckGo too.) Note that I don't want only SO search results, because then that would exclude all the other non-SO stuff that also helps me.

[Here’s](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=symfony2%20formbuilder%20GET%20underscore%20id) an example search on DuckDuckGo (as of 4 Sept 2015) where 11 of the 30 results on the first page are from Stack Overflow scrapers. Google has quite a few Stack Overflow scrapers too, though it also has lot of results that don’t show up on DuckDuckGo that are mixed in.

Edit: I was looking for solutions specifically for StackExchange sites, and more specifically, StackOverflow. The question that is marked as a duplicate is similar enough that it *could* be a duplicate, depending on if specificity is taken into account (but it certainly doesn't answer my question, but then, neither do any of the answers here).

Comment: If you want to block a site, you can add `-site:url.com` in to the end of your query. If you only want to find SO (and nothing else) you can always just use `site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Like I said, there are dozens of these sites, with new ones appearing all the time. I don't have a definitive list of them. I also said I don't want *just* SO results. I already know how to do that.

Comment: FWIW, the way Google deals with them is the best—and most elegant—solution which is to make sure Stack Exchange sites show up at the top of results in the vast majority of cases. Google respects Stack Exchange sites and as a result Stack Exchange sites are pretty much always at the “top of the heap” when doing searches on some topics.

Comment: And why was this moved from superuser? Isn't this exactly what a "power user" question is?

Comment: @FighterJet I cannot speak for who moved it, but I was about to flag it for a move myself. Your issues with search engines fall into the category of end user web applications. The tips given are quite helpful and popped up within minutes of users seeing this question on this specific web applications site. That is why it was moved; this is where this slice of expertise is. Now if your larger question is perhaps setting up a firewall to filter content on your desktop to ensure only Stack Exchange answers come through? Maybe Super User for that. But that would be complex to say the least.

Comment: @JakeGould: Good point.

Comment: There's no specific solution just for SO scrapers. Any solution will be applicable to any set of undesirable domains.

Comment: @AI: My point was, I don't know all of the domains scraping SE sites. If I had a definitive list, I would just set up a keyboard shortcut to paste `-site:badsite1 ... -site:badsite31 -site:badsite32` every time I do a search, but I don't have such a list. My question is, **is there any easy way to block SE scrapers from Google, or preferably, DuckDuckGo? If so, what is it?** Note that, "There is no solution" is a valid answer.

Comment: The Personal Block List extension already mentioned can help. When you see one bad actor in your list of search results, block it and you'll never see it again. Otherwise, you're trying to manage a blacklist that will never stop growing.

Comment: I wish I could use it, but it's limited to Chrome, which I don't use except for dev testing. Furthermore, it's limited to Google, and I would prefer DDG. So even though it doesn't work for me, it may work for others, thus I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Chrome Browser, Goole has released the [Personal Blocklist extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)

> The personal blocklist extension will transmit to Google the patterns
>   that you choose to block. When you choose to block or unblock a
>   pattern, the extension will also transmit to Google the URL of the web
>   page on which the blocked or unblocked search results are displayed.

Comment: That looks like it might work, if I only used Chrome. Good answer. But I use Chrome only in a minority of cases.

Comment: Even though this doesn't work for me, it may work for others, so I'll mark this as the answer.